# Strange Clickonce signing behaviour

Tags: visual-studio, certificate, clickonce, sign

So I built an Outlook VSTO Add-in, and in visual studio on the signing page selected a valid certificate which was bought from a Cert Authority. When I publish the add-in, it all works fine and the installer is trusted.

Here's where it gets weird - When I zipped and emailed it to a colleague they found that the application had an unknown publisher. So I downloaded it from the email I sent them on my pc (the one I built the app with) and sure enough the certificate seemed to be untrusted. Zipping and unzipping the files that I already had locally worked fine and the app was trusted, but the exact same file taken from my email is untrusted.

I'm completely baffled, don't even know how to start googling this issue - anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Did you import the certificate in `certmgr.msc -> Trusted Root Certification`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer for anyone else that runs into this problem.

The hash used by VS when creating a clickonce application is SHA1 (yes, even with VS2019), but SHA1 was depreciated by MS in 2017, meaning anything signed using it is not trusted by later versions of office. Thus you have to publish an unsigned clickonce application with Visual Studio, and then use the "Developer Command Prompt for VS" to sign the .exe with the cert using SHA265.